# How to hide SQL Server database structure

Tags: asp.net-mvc, sql-server-2008

I need to deliver ASP.NET MVC application to client. It uses a SQL Server database.

Is there any way that I hide the database structure from users? They will be admins on server and do installation.

Thanks

Comment: If they're admins on the server machine - then no. There's no way to totally disguise this. One way or another, they can always get to your table structure.

Comment: If you're in a corporate situation where you can't trust the admins, you're already in a deep problem, and it's organizational. If, on the other hand, you're a software supplier and you don't want your customers to be able to access their own data once it's in your product ... I won't include the words here since they'd be moderated

Comment: What's the purpose of hiding the DB structure?